# How to display a property as degrees or angle

Tags: python, interface, add-on

[image]

I would like to make the UI similar to the box (which shows the value as degree) rather than just a number, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting is controlled by the property's [`subtype`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Property.html#bpy.types.Property.subtype). In order to display the content of a `FloatProperty` as degrees/angle, the `subtype` has to be set to `"ANGLE"`.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Subtype example",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Example tab",
    "description": "Subtype example",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy


class ExampleSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    degrees: bpy.props.FloatProperty(subtype="ANGLE")


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel"
    bl_category = "Example tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene.example_settings, "degrees", text="")


classes = (ExampleSettings, EXAMPLE_PT_panel)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.example_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=ExampleSettings)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.example_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the help, Gonna go study more about subtype.